# Compiler option dependency for LLVM pass with CMake

Tags: cmake, llvm

I have a project that needs to be built with an LLVM pass. Here is the project structure:

```
proj/
   instrumentation/
       CMakeLists.txt
       Instrumentation.cpp
   [My project files]
   CMakeLists.txt
```

`instrumentation/CMakeLists.txt` has a target to build the LLVM pass called `MyPass`.

I've added the following the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(instrumentation)
add_compile_options(
            "SHELL:-Xclang -load"
            "SHELL:-Xclang $<TARGET_FILE:MyPass>")
```

Now I just need to add `MyPass` as a dependency for all the targets in my project. I was wondering if there was a way to force `MyPass` to build first so that when compiling other files, the LLVM pass would be present. Maybe there a way to add a target `compile_options` dependencies?

> Note: I'd rather not add the dependency manually to every target because there many targets in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this is to create another project to wrap the compiler executable and automatically build with the LLVM pass. Then rebuild the original project with the wrapped compiler.

[AFL](https://github.com/google/AFL/blob/master/llvm_mode/afl-clang-fast.c) does this exact thing when building with a clang compiler.